# Building pagination in PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, pagination

There are more than 10m records in a table. Assume I display 15 items per page, this query is the simplest one (offset = 1,500,000)

```
select x,y,z 
from table_name
order by x
limit 15
offset 1500000
```

this query takes about 5 seconds. Experts in database suggest the following approach:
I changed the query to this

```
select x,y,z
from table_name
where id > 3649168
order by x
limit 15
```

where `3649168` is the id of last record in page 1,499,999 and it takes about 250ms which is a super fast approach.

To get `3649168`, I set a fields `last_record_id` in each page `i` and in page `i+1` I use this to fetch information. This approach works perfect for the next page but I don't know how to get the previous page.

Comment: 10 million records /15records per page results in  700k  pages not 1.5M - or do i understand something wrong?

Comment: Also  i think if you do not order by id then you will probably get no proper pagination?   

Example: The  records of  x=  a, x=b  ... c,d,e   with ids  of each  5Mio+      so the result will always be a.b.c.d    regardless if id is 6 or 4.9Mio

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig `select * from payment_invoices where deleted_at is null order by id limit 15 offset 1500000` . this is the query and takes 5 seconds

Comment: I meant rather something like 

select x,y,z
from table_name
where id > 3649168
**order by id**,x 
limit 15

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig Actually Id is one of the fields and it is in output.